# CMake: Force to include own boost before system

Tags: cmake

I've tried several ways and read quite some questions on SO, but still can't get my own boost get included before the one in /usr/include.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 btw.

```
BOOST_ROOT="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Libraries/hdm-boost-lib" \ 
BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Libraries/hdm-boost-lib/include" \
Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=TRUE \
Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS=TRUE \
Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Libraries/hdm-boost-lib/lib" \
    cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=TRUE \
    -DBoost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS=TRUE \
    -DBoost_LIBRARY_DIRS:FILEPATH="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Libraries/hdm-boost-lib/lib" \
    .
```

And this is my CMakeLists.txt

```
# set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O2 -std=c++11 -Wall ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/hdm")

set( serializer_SRC
   main.cpp Serializer.cpp
)

add_executable(cadmiral-serializer ${serializer_SRC}) 

set(BOOST_ROOT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Libraries/hdm-boost-lib")
set(BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS "${BOOST_ROOT}/include")
set(BOOST_LIBRARY_DIRS "${BOOST_ROOT}/lib")
#find_package(Boost REQUIRED regex date_time system filesystem thread graph program_options)

#find_package(geos)
#find_package(gdal)

include_directories(
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Libraries/hdm-geo-common/hdm-geo-common/include"
    "${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIRS}"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Libraries/hdm-geo-common/hdm-geo-common/include"
    /opt/hdm/include
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Libraries/hdm-boost-lib/include"
)

#find_library(GDAL_LIB libgdal /opt/hdm/gdal/lib)
#find_library(GEOS_LIB libgeos /opt/hdm/geos/lib)

target_link_libraries(cadmiral-serializer 
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Libraries/hdm-geo-common/hdm-geo-common/libhdm_geo_common.a"
    /opt/hdm/geos/lib/libgeos.so
    /opt/hdm/gdal/lib/libgdal.so
    #${GEOS_LIB}
    #${GDAL_LIB}
)
```

How can I force my own headers in Libraries/hdm-boost-lib/include?

Comment: Don't use full absolute and system-dependent paths in your CMake files. Just don't. That renders CMake useless. Using `BOOST_ROOT` on the command line to the Boost install prefix path should be sufficient for CMake to find it given it's the correct version and library type (type, threading, etc.). Using CMake variables on the command line (or environment) will not work. In your case they are actually being replaced by your shell already.

Comment: The thing is, I only use some of the boost headers and can't install that version of boost to another prefix.

Comment: Add your boost to the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH and use code like ` find_library (<VAR> NAMES name PATHS paths... NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
find_library (<VAR> NAMES name)`, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/find_library.html